# How to make sure `strncmp` doesn't go beyond what it should?

Tags: c

I'm not satisfied with this code.

**Is this the right way to make sure that `strncmp` doesn't go beyond it should?**

I would not want the strings "hello" and "hello-garbage" to be considered equal.  That's why I wrote `strlen(s) + 1`: my idea is that since all strings must end with '\0', then "hello" and "hello-garbage" will not be considered equal.

```
  if (strncmp("small", battery, 
      min(strlen("small") + 1, strlen(battery) + 1)) == 0) {
    bbattery_SmallCrush(g);
  } 
  else 
  if (strncmp("medium", battery, 
      min(strlen("medium") + 1, strlen(battery) + 1)) == 0) {
    bbattery_Crush(g);
  }
  else
  if (strncmp("big", battery, 
      min(strlen("big") + 1, strlen(battery) + 1)) == 0) {
    bbattery_BigCrush(g);
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stdout, "never reached\n");
  }
```

**UPDATE 1**: The origin of battery is user data.  It's an command line argument.  Here's how I'm currently reading it.

```
    strncpy(battery, optarg, min((sizeof battery) - 1, strlen(optarg)));
```

Can I be sure `optarg` will always be properly terminated?  In this case, I need only check up to `sizeof battery` and that would answer my question.

Comment: `strncmp` will still stop on '\0'. It may stop sooner, as requested. Also, it is generally *pointless* to use strncmp with strlen: it is effectively strcmp, as limited by strlen's ability (or lack of) to determine the length.

Comment: Follow-up: since `strcmp("hello", "hello-garbage")` won't consider the strings equal, why not use it?

Comment: What sort of texts can occur in `battery`?

Comment: You do have a thing for the `strn*` functions, don't you?

Comment: The right question.  I updated the question with that information.  (Thanks as well for the strlen-comment and the pointlessness of using it with strncmp.)

Comment: @MOehm I'm learning to use it. :-)

Comment: (But it would be interesting to know what you are trying to achieve. Obviously it's not just string comparison. Is `battery` a line that should start with "big" / "medium" / "small" and you are trying to detect that? All the code with `strn`-something plus `strlen`  looks overly complicated to me.)

Comment: @MOehm `battery` is copied from `optarg`, so it comes from the command line.  The sequence of checks in the question is to make sure only the strings "small", "medium", "big" are entered by the user.  Anything else is illegal.

Comment: Optarg will always be NUL-terminated. That is guaranteed. Otoh, `strncpy` does not guarantee that the copy will be NUL-terminated. It is hardly ever the right function to use. Anyway, there is no need to make a copy of the command-line option. If you don't modify it, nothing else will.

Comment: Why do you have to copy `optarg` at all? Can't you just say something like `if (strcmp(optarg, "big") == 0) ...`?

Comment: I process other command line arguments which will overwrite `optarg` eventually.

Comment: I don't know, you seem to approach this from the wrong end. You need to look at that string only once at the beginning to determine which of big/medim/small you have. And if these other arguments get changed, why not make a copy of those? (Frankly, I'm not seeing how changing other arguments should change this one.)

Comment: I check then during the `getopt` parsing.  But then I check them all again to see which battery of tests I should run.  I could instead set numbers such as `BATTERY_SMALL` for the batteries and so I'd be free from checking strings to see which battery I should run.  (That's probably a better idea!  Thanks!)

Comment: @melba: optarg is a pointer. It is changed to point at something else, but the thing it pointed to before is still there. If you save *the pointer* (eg. `const char* battery = optarg;`), `battery` will still point at the same string at the end. No need for a copy.

Comment: @rici Interesting.  So I never need to copy `optarg` because it is never a string, but just a pointer.  Got it.  So `battery` will just point to argv[I] for some `I`.  Thanks very much for this info.